# Encountered error while installing MEGAcmd at make step

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, makefile, build, gnu-make

[Picture describing the make error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdV83.png) Despite of satisfying pre-requisites of MEGAcmd with packages listed on its Github page, the make step is encountering error. Any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,

Shivank Parashar

Followed with the instructions to compile the tool as mentioned in MEGAcmd's Github page.

git clone https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd.git
cd MEGAcmd && git submodule update --init --recursive

sh autogen.sh
./configure
make (Encountered the error in this step)

The error screenshot has been attached herewith.

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** which just represent a *textual* information. Instead, paste the error message into the question post as **text**. See also [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.